# Log4j TimeBasedRollingPolicy doesn't work

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Now I want my log files rolling in runtime every minute, and if size of the log file is more than 250MB. Size condition is working, but log it isn't divide it my time.
There is my log4j.properties:

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=./logs/application_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}{UTC}.log
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=250000000
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html

Comment: I'm doing exact things, but have no result :(